# How to prove that infimum of $A = \{\frac{n}{2^n} : n \in N\}$ is 0?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

How to prove that infimum of  $A = \{\frac{n}{2^n} : n \in N\}$ is 0?

Could you explain this to me step by step?

Comment: I've mistaken, now it's correct.

Comment: $0$ is the infimum.

Comment: See the corollary of the least upper bound property.

Answer (score 1):

This set definitely admits an infimum. The only sets without an infimum are the one that do not admit any lower bound. This one is bounded below by $0$ so an infimum exists.

Comment: The empty set admits a lower bound, but has no infimum. But for non-empty sets, you are right.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed it's only for natural numbers, sorry.